# I have a pond with animals, I want to run them through a loop

Tags: java

I have a pond with animals, I want to run them through a loop, each of them has a swimming interface except for an eagle, they are all inherited from animals, why, when I create an array, I cannot call the swimming method, but separately I can ???

```
Animal [] animals = {fish, carp, tiger, elephant , eagle};
for (Animal a : animals) {
    System.out.println(a.getType() + " плавает " + (I can not) a.swim() + " метров");
    
        (can)   fish.swim();
}
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: You can't do this, unless `Animal` has a `swim()` method; or, if you cast the `Animal` to a type that has a `swim()` method (having checked it's an instance of that type, ofc).

Comment: are fish, carp, tiger etc. types of their own classes that extend Animal? i.e. class Carp extends Animal; while also implementing the swim interface? if the Animal class does not implement the Swim interface then it is cannot invoke it's method. to better help we would need to see the class declarations

Comment: You shouldn't be able to call a `swim` method from `eagle` unless it has access to that method.  But the interface that has the swim method should be implemented by all animals.  Then the animal simply returns the correct `boolean`.

Answer (score 1):

You did not post the Animal class implementation or Swimming interface definition but I would presume the answer is that the Animal class does not implement that swim interface.

When you call fish directly you know you have an object that implements Swimming, but an Object the type Animal does not give you any such guarantee. You can fix this by adding the interface to the Animal class and simply declare the class as abstract.

Comment: Let's get an animal that doesn't swim. That is, Animal will not have swim by default, as it should. How then can we make sure that we do not have a situation, so that there is no risk of trying to force swim in an animal that does not swim?

Comment: @АртемОдинцов You can add a default implementation in your Animal class e.g. `boolean swim(){ return false;}`. In your animals that do swim implement   `@Override boolean swim(){ return true;}`

Answer (score 0):

It gives you that error because the compiler is intelligent enough to understand that an animal instance of the list does not implement the interface, preventing you an unhandled exception. To solve you can check at runtime if the animal instance implements the interface:

```
Animal [] animals = {fish, carp, tiger, elephant , eagle};
for (Animal a : animals) {
    if(a instance of swimmingInterface){
       ((swimmingInterface)a).swim();
     }
   }
```

or

```
 if(SwimInterface.class.isAssignableFrom(a.getClass())){
    a.swim();
 }
```

Comment: It's `instanceof` instead of `instance of`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just have all the animals implement the interface?

```
interface DoesSwim {
   public boolean doesSwim();
}

class Animal implements DoesSwim {
   private boolean swims = true; // or default could be false.
   public boolean doesSwim() {
      return swims; 
   }
   public void setSwimmable(boolean val) {
      swims = val;
   }
}

class Deer extends Animal {
   setSwimmable(false);
}
```

You could also forget the interface and make it a part of the `Animal` class. Or you could have a `Characteristics` interface and have more options. Or have sub classes of `Animal` that swim and those that don't.  Then subclass those appropriately.  There are many options at your disposal.